# Password on Dialogflow agent: Telegram and Facebook

Tags: dialogflow-es, telegram-bot, facebook-messenger-bot

I would like to know if there is an easy way to put a password to control access to a telegram bot and tb a Facebook chatbot that I built in Dialogflow. I am interested in charging monthly for access to the tools that I built and for that I needed some kind of premium access and I do not know how to do it , even though I have searched a lot on this site. 
Since I am not from the area of ​​computer science and I do not know programming, I would be very grateful if someone can send me  a tutorial. Thanks a lot for  your help!

Comment: https://core.telegram.org/bots#deep-linking ; Generate id and use